# How to enable SSL Handshake Debug logs in Red Hat OpenShift application

Tags: java, openshift, sslhandshakeexception, ssl-handshake

I need some help to enable SSL Handshake debug logs in Openshift. I have an application running in Openshift container and created POD for that application. I'm not able to enable SSL Handshake debug logs and able to see only the application logs in the POD logs.

For stand alone application, we can enable SSL Handshake debug logs using below system parameter passing in java command.

```
       -Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake
```

For Openshift, I tried to enable manually (`System.setParameter('javax.net.debug', 'ssl,handshake')` in Java, but not able to see debug logs in the POD application logs.

Can someone please suggest to enable SSL Handshake debug logs in the Red Hat Openshift container.

Please let me know if you need more info.